# How to save newly added columns of handsontable jquery plugin into database table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

I am using handsontable jquery plugin. It has a feature for adding new columns. Now my problem is when the new column is added how am i going to save it into the database?. Because  table has fixed columns. Any suggestions ??

Comment: It really depends on you application. What do you need new columns for? In many cases, I have serialized all grid data into one JSON string and put that string into a TEXT/BLOB column in the database.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new column in handsontable, create the new column in the database too.
You can do this with the [event](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events):

```
afterCreateCol (index: Number)
```

"Callback is fired when a new column is created"